# Plotly animation Python, PlotlyRequestError: Figure field is invalid

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to animate time series data using plotly. I've successfully made a non-animated plot using the same data: https://plot.ly/~peterasmuth/4. Ultimately, what I'd like to do is create an animation where the color of each point changes based on the temperature at a given time. In an effort to simplify the process I tried to animate the temperature change at a single point.

```
weather.head()
temp_f lat        long        timestamp
66.9   45.683189  -111.028275 2018-05-04 13:21:00
66.8   45.683189  -111.028275 2018-05-04 13:33:00
66.7   45.683189  -111.028275 2018-05-04 13:52:00
68.5   45.683189  -111.028275 2018-05-04 14:06:00
68.5   45.683189  -111.028275 2018-05-04 14:08:00
```

None of the plotly animation tutorials covered how to do this exactly, but I did my best to adapt the ones I could find (ordered by how much I used them):  https://plot.ly/python/animations/, https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-animation/, https://plot.ly/python/heatmap-animation/,  https://plot.ly/python/gapminder-example/

Here's my attempt:

```
temps = list(weather.temp_f)
columns = []
for i in range(0, len(temps)):
    new_column = Column(temps[i], 'temp{}'.format(i))
    columns.append(new_column)

grid = Grid(columns)

#Layout dictionary
layout = go.Layout(
        autosize = True,
        hovermode = 'closest',
        #The mapbox dictionary gives a bunch of parameters to the Mapbox API
        mapbox = dict(
        #Omitted for brevity
        ),
    )

#Data dictionary
data = [
    go.Scattermapbox(

    #Since my data are all collected from the same weather station, there is only one point on the scatter
    #I plan to scale this up to an arbitrary number of stations
    lat = weather.lat,
    lon = weather.long,

    #Makes it a scatter plot
    mode = 'markers',

    #Sets parameters for the appearance of the markers
    marker = dict(
        size = 8,
        #The marker color is matched to the temperature for that observation
        color = grid.get_column_reference('temp0'),
        colorscale = [ [0,"rgb(5, 10, 172)"],[0.35,"rgb(40, 60, 190)"], \
                       [0.5,"rgb(70, 100, 245)"],[0.6,"rgb(90, 120, 245)"],\ 
                       [0.7,"rgb(106, 137, 247)"],[1,"rgb(220, 220, 220)"] ]
        ),
    text=['Station xyz'],
    )
]
#Frames dictionary, this is most likely where the problem is!! I was mainly following the filled area animation for this part.
frames = [{'data':
             [{'marker':[
                 #I want the color of the point to change based on the temperature for that observation
                 {'color': grid.get_column_reference('temp{}'.format(k))}
             ]}
         ]} for k in range(0, len(temps))]

#Generate the figure using the above parameters
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout, frames=frames)
py.icreate_animations(fig, filename='Station xyz')
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
PlotlyRequestError: Figure field is invalid. Reason: Raw data arrays are not 
allowed at this endpoint. Use grid references instead. Raw data found at the 
following paths in the figure [('data', 0, u'lat'), ('data', 0, u'lon'), 
('data', 0, u'text')]
```

Can anybody help me figure this out?

Comment: Did you attempt to put your data into a Plotly grid and then reference it directly? [Good example](https://plot.ly/python/gapminder-example/)